# Function of Button Two is already defined function in Button One

Tags: jquery

I hope this makes sense... I have buttons A & B with already defined functions (Next & Previous). I want to create two new buttons (Button C & D) and link them to the already existing functions in A & B. Is there code in jQuery to do this?

I am using FuelUX Wizard and here is there code for the next button (I think):

```
this.$nextBtn = this.$element.find( 'button.btn-next' );

this.$nextBtn.on( 'click.fu.wizard', $.proxy( this.next, this ) );
```

Comment: You bind the 2 new buttons to the next and previous functions that you have in your code.

Comment: It will be easier to understand what you're talking about if you can share the code you have already developed.

Comment: There is code to do this. What have you done?

Comment: add your code to a jsFiddle so we can see what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Post your here or in jsfiddle,so to get better idea of it.

Comment: I am using fuelUX wizard so here is what I pulled from there code as the function for the next button (I think).

Comment: this.$nextBtn = this.$element.find( 'button.btn-next' );

this.$nextBtn.on( 'click.fu.wizard', $.proxy( this.next, this ) );

Comment: update your question... not comments

Comment: Just seen the jsfiddle link so I will post it there and send the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this effect with using HTML classes.

ie.

```
<div class="next">A</div>
<div class="prev">B</div>
<div class="next">C</div>
<div class="prev">D</div>

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('next')){
        //next function
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
        //prev function
    }
});
```

Comment: Adding the same class name makes sense. Okay this worked. Thanks a lot for your help